# my app gets installed on the android emulator but it fails to run and there are no errors

Tags: android

I have developed a chat application using socket programming having  1 client and 1 server.
I am running 2 projects. 1 for client and 1 for server.
My client app gets installed on the emulator but when I click on the icon, it doesnt run.
There are no errors:

```
package com.client.chat;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ClientActivity extends Activity{

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private String serverIpAddress = "10.0.2.2";
    private static final int TCP_SERVER_PORT = 6000;  
    private Button bt;
    private Socket s;
    private TextView tv;
    String error;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    //    bt=(Button)findViewById(R.id.cbtn);
        tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.clienttext);
      tcpclient();
    }

    private void tcpclient(){
    try{
        InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIpAddress);
        s = new Socket(serverAddr, TCP_SERVER_PORT);
    }catch(UnknownHostException e){e.printStackTrace(); error=e.toString(); 
        tv.setText(error);
    }catch(IOException e){e.printStackTrace();
        error=error.toString();
        tv.setText(error);
    }

        try{
                  EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.clientedit);
                  String str = et.getText().toString();
                  BufferedWriter out = null;
                   out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()));
                 String outMsg=str+System.getProperty("line.separator");

    //  String outMsg = "TCP connecting to " + TCP_SERVER_PORT + System.getProperty("line.separator"); 
        out.write(str);
        out.flush();
        Log.i("TcpClient", "sent: " + outMsg);
                  Log.d("Client", "Client sent message");
    }catch(UnknownHostException e){e.printStackTrace();
    error=e.toString();
    tv.setText(error);
    }catch(IOException e){e.printStackTrace();
    error=e.toString();
    tv.setText(error);
    }

         //accept server response
       BufferedReader in=null;
        try{

        in= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
        String inMsg = in.readLine() + System.getProperty("line.separator");
        Log.i("TcpClient", "received: " + inMsg);

        //close connection
        s.close();
        }catch(UnknownHostException e){error=e.toString();
            tv.setText(error);
        }catch(IOException e){error=e.toString();
            tv.setText(error);
        }
        finish();
    }
}
```

Please help!

Comment: Try running "adb logcat", or check out the logcat tab if you are running from eclipse, this may give you some useful info

Answer (score 1):

remove the finish() or put a break point on it. I bet its hitting that and exiting.

Also, I don't see a while loop, or a new thread or any mechanism to keep the client alive, the tcpClient() will run to the end, and exit the activity, since you only have one activity, it will exit the app.

Answer (score 0):

Run the tcpClient() in thread and it should work.

```
Thread t = new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                tcpclient();
            }
        };
        t.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Running the tcpClient() in a thread should be done, yes.  but if you don't wrap the readline() in a while loop with a Thread.Sleep() at the end of the loop, the thread will just run to the finish() and exit.  I'm not sure if your activity will exit it may.. you need to keep the thread alive by a loop with a sleep() in it.  Just putting it in a thread will do nothing.

```
in= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
while(!shutDown){
        String inMsg = in.readLine() + System.getProperty("line.separator");
        Log.i("TcpClient", "received: " + inMsg);
        Thread.Sleep(1000); // sleep one second
}
```